Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^n}-1}, \text{where } a \in \mathbb{N}, a \geq 2$
I am interested in the following family of series:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^n}-1}, \text{where } a \in \mathbb{N}, a \geq 2
\end{equation}
Is there a nice way to find the value of this sum or at least some kind of simpler formula for the partial sum?
I tried to take particular cases, such as $a = 2$, but made no progress.
The only thing I managed to prove is that the sum is equal to
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a - 1} - \frac{1}{a+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n}}+1}
\end{equation}
but it doesn't really help.
Proof
$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^n}-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a^{2^{n-1}})^2-1^{2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a^{2^{n-1}} - 1)\cdot(a^{2^{n-1}}+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{(a^{2^{n-1}}+1) - (a^{2^{n-1}}-1)}{(a^{2^{n-1}} - 1)\cdot(a^{2^{n-1}}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{a^{2^{n-1}}-1} - \frac{1}{a^{2^{n-1}}+1}) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n-1}}-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n-1}}+1}) \iff$
$S = \frac{1}{2}\cdot ((S + \frac{1}{a - 1}) - (\frac{1}{a+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n}}+1})) \iff S = \frac{1}{a - 1} - \frac{1}{a+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n}}+1}$
For $a = 2$ we get $S = 1 -\frac{1}{3} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n}}+1} = \frac{2}{3} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{2^{n}}+1}$
I also couldn't find anything online about them, therefore some papers or articles you know would be extremely helpful.

Show us what your attempt was...

Aside from the somewhat trivial fact that (letting $x=1/a$), this is the generating function for the $2$-adic valuation $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\upsilon_2(n)x^n$$I doubt there is much else to say about this particular series... I could be wrong though.

This series converges very quickly (unless $a$ is extremely near to $1$) , so an excellent numerical approximation can easily be established. So why searching for a closed form which has to be evaluted anyway numerically , so we gain not much.

Simple manipulations lead to $\frac12\left[ \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{a^n-1} - \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{a^n+1} \right]$. I am not sure if that helps much.
